# Will Ubuntu 18.04 get an nginx version compiled with OpenSSL 1.1.1?

Tags: 18.04, nginx, openssl, tls

I run multiple servers with Ubuntu 18.04 and nginx. Updating to 18.10/19.04 is not an option.

I'd like to activate TLS 1.3 support for my webserver.

I know I need an nginx version built with OpenSSL 1.1.1 (and I like to stick on the Ubuntu repo for nginx and not compile it myself or get it from another repo)

Currently, `nginx -V` puts out:

> nginx version: nginx/1.17.0 built by gcc 7.3.0 (Ubuntu
>   7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)  built with OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017 (running with OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018)

So, no chance yet to run TLS 1.3

On [OpenSSL 1.1.1 With TLS 1.3 Being Back-Ported To Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-18.04-OpenSSL-1.1.1-TLS) it says:

> Following the introduction of OpenSSL 1.1.1 there will also be SRU
>   updates for enabling TLSv1.3 support within Apache and OpenSSH.

However, I cannot find any information on nginx. So, will Ubuntu 18.04 get an nginx version with TLS support/built with OpenSSL 1.1.1?

(Sorry, if this question is off topic because it will become outdated soonish probably.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like finally the nginx version built with OpenSSL 1.1.1 is there. Today, after running an update I got for `nginx -V`:

> nginx version: nginx/1.17.2 built by gcc 7.4.0 (Ubuntu
>   7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)  built with OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018